# Pull SoundCloud view count for individual track

Tags: soundcloud

Im wanting to pull play count data for an individual track on SoundCloud. I've seen various examples that pull total plays for all users tracks, but not for individual tracks. I'm very new to coding and will probably not be the one handling the final coding, but was just wondering if anyone already has the answer.

For example, I would like to keep track of the play count for this track:

https://soundcloud.com/llucid/fish-grease-prod-louis-futon

If you guys can help me, I'd truly appreciate it.

Kind regards

Comment: Please show some research effort, to us its a 'here is my problem, now go deal with it' type of question. You didnt even specify which language you intend to use. Please learn programming basics before asking here!

Comment: My apologies Uli. I wasn't aware of the nature of the site in detail. If it does help, this is a past example of something similar to what I was asking for an overall playcount for an artist. I understand if this is something that I should look through thoroughly before posting, so feel free to ignore it.

Comment: This is the question from the past: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15331666/how-to-display-playback-count-for-a-user-using-the-soundcloud-api

Comment: No problem! All of us are learning on the fly, just do better next time ;-) For example, read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The previous question wasn't so straightforward because a users total track playcount for all tracks is not readily available.  But playcount for a single track is right there for you to get.

I find myself working with track ids more often than urls to tracks.  But if you just have the url, you can still resolve it to a full track resource, which would include the playcount.

I don't know what language you use, but I use php and heres the code to get that tracks playcount.  But I'll tell you right now, unless you can make some sense of the api docs ([located here](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide)) then i think you are in over your head.  This code is copy/paste from api docs.

```
<?php
require_once 'Services/Soundcloud.php';

// create a client object with your app credentials
$client = new Services_Soundcloud('YOUR_CLIENT_ID');

// a permalink to a track
$track_url = 'https://soundcloud.com/llucid/fish-grease-prod-louis-futon';

// resolve track URL into track resource
$track = json_decode($client->get('resolve', array('url' => $track_url)), true);

$track_playcount = $track['playback_count'];
echo $track_playcount;
```

Comment: Fantastic. This is exactly what I'm after. Will try implementing it soon enough. Thanks again